# Operation contract name is different but is still throwing errors

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have a WCF service that has an interface with the following operation contracts:

```
    [OperationContract(Name = "uploadFile")]
    void uploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request);

    [OperationContract(Name = "uploadFileAsync")]
    Task uploadFileAsync(RemoteFileInfo request);
```

When I try to host this service, it gives me the error that I cannot have 2 contracts with the same name and that "uploadFile" and "uploadFIleAsync" violate this rule. As you can see I have them named differently where one is just `uploadFile` and one is `uploadFileAsync` so how is WCF seeing them as the "same name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an `OperationContract`, WCF automatically creates the async version of the method for you. WCF names this method the same as the original, but tacks as Async on the end. With that said, you have two methods called `uploadFileAsync`, so you are getting the error. So change your interface to be:

```
[OperationContract]
void uploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request);
```

You will still be able to call your method in your client by:

```
var result = await client.uploadFileAsync(request);
```